# Adding a 'view all' endpoint to restful Django

Tags: python, django, rest, routes

I have this row in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^rss/(?P<rss_id>\d+)/', views.RSSList.as_view())
```

I want to be able to server also something like

```
http://example.com/rss
```

Which will show the complete rss list.

How can I add it while keeping the id option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the given line to:

```
url(r'^rss/(?P<rss_id>\d*)/?', views.RSSList.as_view())
```

The character '*' means zero or more character.

Comment: Did you notice '?' after last slash?

Comment: `?` means slash is optional.